# Java+Gradle build stucks on compileTestJava stage on JDK 11+, but works fine on JDK 1.8, no errors in console

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, jvm

Having a problem with updating my test project to the JDK 11+ (for now it's using Java 1.8 which is out of support).

I use Gradle 7.3 for compiling the project. Everything works fine with JDK 1.8, but when I change the JDK version for 11 or 14 build hangs on :compileTestJava stage.
There are no errors in the console, it doesn't fail. Just hanging forever.

Attaching Thread Dump of JVM if that helps:

https://gist.github.com/artemryazantsev/3ef7c35ac150bda4281aeaae7697ee7b

Comment: Looks similar to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15112 . I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with JDK 11(Amazon Corretto) and Gradle 7.3.3. Please share a [minimal reproducible project sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clarify your JDK vendor.

Comment: Does it work from the command line outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov it is the same from command line as well..

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in my code related to specific usage of Lombok library, closing as not an issue